# Is there a shorter way to update a svelte store?

Tags: javascript, svelte-store

I have a svelte store that uses this data:

```
{ "books": [
   {
      "id": "F0tE_25",
      "title": "Abc",
       ...
   },
      "id": "zNPAQit",
      "title": "Ny, Ny",
       ...
   }
 ]
}
```

I edit a book in a form and call the function below to update the store (id is the book id to update and bookData is the updated data (from the form):

```
updateBook: (id, bookData) => {
   bookstore.update(items => {
   const index = items.findIndex(i => i.id ===id)
   const updatedBook = {...items[index], ...bookData}
   const updatedBooks = [...items]
   updatedBooks[index] = updatedBook
   return updatedBooks
})
}
```

It works. It just seems like a lot of juggling to perform an update. Wondered if there was a better way?

Comment: `Store.update(updateFn)` is essentially just calling `Store.set(updateFn(Store.state))`

A less cumbersome way to do this would be to have the store be formatted as an Object where the ids are the keys. That might be overkill if this works for you though.

Comment: fairly standard in react is to simply `map` checking for id match, no reason it wouldn't work here. `bookstore.update(items => items.map(item => item.id === id ? {...item, ...bookData} : item))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems associated with the approach in the question viz use of `findIndex`. If the item with the given id doesn't exist the value of `index` will be `-1` which will result `items[index]` to be `undefined` and will be the cause of other undesired behavior.

You can use `.map()` to eliminate and simplify the update. Here is an example.

```js
updateBook: (id, bookData) => {
  bookstore.update(items =>
    items.map(item => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        return { ...item, ...bookData };
      }
      return item;
    })
  );
}
```

---

Edited: @pilchard's answer might be even clearer implementation with the use of ternary operator.

```js
updateBook: (id, bookData) => {
  bookstore.update(items =>
    items.map(item => {
      return item.id === id ? { ...item, ...bookData } : item;
    })
  );
}
```

---

Hope that helps.

Comment: map(), of course. Much neater. Works perfectly.